# How can I set a shader to a Path in xml in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, shader, android-xml, android-vectordrawable

I have created a vector asset in xml with a single path like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="64dp"
android:width="64dp"
android:viewportHeight="600"
android:viewportWidth="600">

<group android:name="name"
    android:pivotX="0.5"
    android:pivotY="0.5">
    <path
        android:name="namepath"
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="**some path data**" />
</group>
</vector>
```

Here I have used a single fill Color - Is there any way I can apply a Gradient / Shader on this in xml?

Comment: Something like this? https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawable-gradients-part1/

Comment: Thanks, I found this link earlier, and it fixed my issue! Wish it worked pre api-24 though